# FFMPEG GT() Not Working

Tags: ffmpeg

Consider this part of the script:

```
FOR %%G IN (Eqr_360_????.jpg) DO (


ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=size=3888x3888 -vf format=pix_fmts=gray16le,geq=Y-^(20*^(Y/1939^)*^(3887-X^)/3887^)*gt(Y,1880)  -frames 1 -y %FF%YmapCenter.pgm

)
pause
```

Adding "" around this line does not get the script to work. Went for the alternate to then added ^ to protect the parentheses ( ) but gt() could not be protected.

Using "" about the line or using ^ to protect the parentheses () always returns the error ... Unknown function gt(Y,1880

Removing the *gt(Y,1880) allows the script to work.

In a second attempt I removed the CMD FOR statement and set the file name directly. This means there is no command shell conflict, but the error message persists ... Unknown function gt(Y,1880

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to escape the the brackets in `gt(Y,1880)` ie `gt^(Y,1880^)`

Comment: Adding the ^ before the parentheses ( as you suggested within gt(Y, 1880) continues to return error  Unknown function. Adding ^ to both parentheses also returns error Unknown function.

Comment: Some progress but conflict with FOR %%G IN (Eqr_360_????.jpg) DO ( ...  ) persist.  I changed the instruction script to read:   ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=size=3888x3888 -vf format=pix_fmts=gray16le,geq='if(gt(Y,1880),Y-20*(Y/1939)*(3887-X)/3887,Y)'  -frames 1 -y %FF%YmapCenter.pgm    .... and it works when run without FOR DO ( ...). This means gt() only returns logic True/Faults and not 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified two problems:

1. gt() not working
2. FOR %%G IN (Eqr_360_????.jpg) DO ( conflicts with gt() parentheses as quotes do not protect gt() nor does ^.

Solution for problem 1) was resolved by understanding gt() returns only True or False and not 1 or 0. This means gt() cannot be used as arithmetic function.
Instead the IF(x,y,z) function was used in conjunction with gt() and solution for problem 2). The script used was:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=size=3888x3888 -vf "format=pix_fmts=gray16le,geq=if(gt(Y,1880),Y-^(20*^(Y/1939^)*^(3887-X^)/3887^),Y)"  -frames 1 -y %FF%YmapCenter.pgm
```

Solution for problem 2) was to substitute expression for the FOR %%G IN (Eqr_360_????.jpg) DO (. In its place the following was used:

```
@echo off
:START
if "%~1" == "" goto END

Set "G=%~n1%~x1"    ::This is the file name with extension

shift
goto START
:END
```

Granted this did not enable batch processing of files but it works with FFMPEG parentheses.